# Data Source (Object / Entity Framework) Fields are sorted alphabetically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, datasource

I am currently working on Entity Framework (it's my first time)

I want to drag and drop auto bound controls via datasource into a form but they are always in alphabetical order. I have watched several videos and have searched the internet but the fields are always arranged depending on what field comes first on the database.

This is how the order of the fields are in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SupplierMasterlist](
    [SupplierID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SupplierName] [varchar](125) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ContactNumber] [varchar](125) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ContactPerson] [varchar](125) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Currency] [varchar](12) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [isActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
```

But when I drag and drop the controls to the form (from the datasource pane) this is the order I get:

-Address
-ContactNumber
-ContactPerson
-Currency
-Description
-isActive
-SupplierID
-SupplierName

Is there  a special setting for this? i can't seem to find any tips or what i am doing wrong on google. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The columns are sorted alphabetically in data source. One way to prevent this is set AutoGenerateColumns of datagrid to true.

```
AutoGenerateColumns = "true"
```

Remove all the labels and textboxes generated in the forms, but keep the data binding of the grid.